# NameError When Creating Subclass in Spyder IPython

Tags: python, spyder, nameerror

I am on Spyder 4.1.2 with Python 3.7.6, with the following run preference deselected.

> Remove all variables before execution

I have 2 separate Python files. The first file starts with:

```
class Fruit(object):
    def __init__(self, colour):
    ...
```

The second file starts with:

```
class Apple(Fruit):
    ...
```

After running the first file then followed by the second file, I will receive a NameError despite the class Fruit existing after being created in the first file.

> NameError: name 'Fruit' is not defined

While I understand I should use the import function, an online course I am currently on had this professor that was able to run the second file without importing the first file.

Comment: Your prof either imported it or else entered the class definition directly.  It had to come from someplace.  You need to either `from file1 import Fruit` or `from file1 import *`.

Comment: @TomKarzes, wouldn't the first file create the class Fruit in the environment?For example, if I were to run the first file; then type the whole second file directly into IPython console, everything runs fine and I don't encounter any error.

Comment: You would have to run it in the same session.  If it's in a script, and it invokes the Python interpreter, then that session will end when the script terminates.